# Handling JSON and form data request with Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working on simple Spring-MVC application and I love new Spring REST features. I'd like to use the same method to process regular form and JSON data. It seems to be a little tricky, however. For example, method

```
public @ResponseBody String process(@RequestBody Bean bean);
```

will work for JSON request (Content-type: application/json), and

```
public @ResponseBody String process(Bean bean);
```

will match request with Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

These methods are obviously will have almost the same content, so I'd prefer to avoid such duplication. With Jersey it's possible with `@Consumes` annotations, but I can't figure out how to do it with Spring.

Comment: What is the return type for those methods? I thought you needed to specify a "type" after the @ResponseBody annotation or at least void?

Comment: Oh, sorry missed return types. They are irrelevant, in fact. It seems, Spring matches request by arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the above declaration won't compile, because you are having duplicate signature.

Btw, `@Consumes` wouldn't help, I think, because it only designates what content type the method can handle.

In spring you can specify the content-type with

```
@RequestMapping(headers="Content-Type=application/json")
```

Comment: @Consumes is for Jersey, sorry for misunderstanding. Thanks for your remark about compilation, but these signatures are just for demonstration purposes. What I really need is not to have different methods for JSON and form data processing, which seems to be impossible with Spring MVS.

Comment: @rsvato and how is it possible in Jersey? I've shown the equivallent of Consumes - it's "headers". But how would it work in Jersey? You can specify that the method handles both content types (and so can you in spring), and then?

Comment: And then approriate MessageBodyReader implementation will decode request. So it's just a question of provider (in Jersey). You mean it's impossible to process several content types with one method?

Comment: @rsvato - I was asking how will you do it. I've done very little with jax-rs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, i'm annotating method with @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml", "application/form"}) which means that this method may process all three types of requests.

Comment: @rsvato well, with the `headers={..}` you can do the same thing. But the problem point is the following `@RequestBody`.

Comment: When I'm adding @RequestMapping(headers = "Content-type=application/*") to Spring controller method, and when I'm using @RequestBody on one of method parameters, I can actually process JSON and XML, but for form posts I'm getting error org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm saying. But without @RequestBody I can't decode JSON data in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Just add @RestController annotation for the controller class.